# Bootstrap form not styled correctly

Tags: wordpress, forms, editor, wysiwyg

I'm having some problems with the bootstrap forms. For some reason they all get messed up.
This is what it should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRheb.png
This is how it shows up on my page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXwFs.png
As you can see, it makes the input box smaller and it places 'br' code behind every line. It also puts a random 'p' in it without any closing tag. (nowhere to be found on the page)
My input code:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Legend</legend>
    <label>Label name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
    <span class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</span>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The output code in the browser:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Legend</legend>
    <p>
      <label>Label name</label><br />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…"><br />
      <span class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</span><br />
      <label class="checkbox"><br />
        <input type="checkbox"> Check me out<br />
      </label><br />
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button><br />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

So my question is; What could possibly be causing this and how do I fix it?
I'm using Bootstrap v2.3.2 as a theme on wordpress and followed this tutorial, so most of my code looks like it.
blog.teamtreehouse (dot) com/responsive-wordpress-bootstrap-theme-tutorial

Thank you for taking the time to read this. :)

Comment: Please include the images in the post instead of on imgur.

Comment: Not possible. I'm a new user. New users have all sorts of restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Bootstrap, but with your WordPress editor (or how you're using it).

You'll need to use a plain text editor or reconfigure what your editor does to HTML on save.

Comment: This is my first time using stackoverflow. I thought the Enter wasn't working very well with creating alinea's, so I used br tags everywhere, haha.

And yes, thanks for your reply, I'll look into the wordpress editor. It was my first thought already as well